# Exception Handling in If statement?

Tags: java, android, exception, if-statement

I'm struggling to create a very simple app. There are Product Names with matching Product Numbers. User enters a Number and the corresponding Name appears.

`editTextField1` = the number user types

`button1` = the search button

`editTextField2` = the product name appears

Now my code is working but there is only one problem, when the user doesn't enter anything and clicks on `button1` the app crashes. So I need some sort of exception handler maybe? Im struggling to get my head around it. I know how I'm coding, by declaring loads of variables, is long-winded lol.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button1;
private EditText editText1;
private EditText editText2;
private int a = 123;
private String b = "TV";
private int c  = 333;
private String d = "Radio";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    View.OnClickListener myOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            double pNumber = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
            if(pNumber == a){
                editText2.setText(b);
            }
           else if (pNumber == c){
                editText2.setText(d);
            }
            else
                editText2.setText("Invalid Product Number");
            }


    };

    button1.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
```

Comment: You could simply deactivate the `Button` and only activate it when some text is entered in the `TextField`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
View.OnClickListener myOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = editText1.getText().toString();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            // EditText1 is not empty
            try {
                double pNumber = Double.parseDouble(text);
                if(pNumber == a)
                    editText2.setText(b);
                else if (pNumber == c){
                    editText2.setText(d);
                else
                    editText2.setText("Invalid Product Number");
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
                // Invalid input, not a double
                editText2.setText("Invalid double input"); 
            }
        }
        else {
            // EditText1 is empty
            editText2.setText("EditText1 is empty"); 
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Works like a charm, may God bless you

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to Spartas Answer, it would also be a good idea to check for a valid Double input:

```
try {
    double pNumber = Double.parseDouble(text);
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //Do ExceptionHandling
}
```

Comment: In what circumstance wouldn't it be a double? The user can only type numbers and not letters or demical points.

Comment: Normally its possible to also enter non numeric values into an edittext input. With the code you provided to us, it would be possible to also enter non numeric values. If you have made any additional restrictions in the xml file or only show the numeric keypad to the user, then a check is maybe not needed. But it never hurts :)

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 ways how you can handle this

1) Use try - catch

```
try{
 double pNumber = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
  }catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //show a message to user 

  }
```

2) Use input sanitation

```
  String number = editText1.getText().toString();
  boolean isNumber = number.matches("^-?\\d+$"));//haven't tried this though
  if(!isNumber) //if not number
    //show a message to user
```

Comment: wouldn't be the variable number always not an instanceof Number, because you have declared it as a String?
As String only inherits from Object
And Number also only inherits from Object